# if statement in JSTL

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jstl

I want to make an if statment in JSTL .. Here is what i want to make:

```
<c:set var="sex" value="${param.sex}"/>

 <c:if test="$(param.sex=='male')" >
     //set the sex to zero
 </c:if>
 <c:if test="$(param.sex=='female')" >
     //set the sex to one
 </c:if>
```

and then use the sex in the where clause like this

```
<sql:query dataSource="${dbcon}" var="result">
 select firstname,lastname from members where sex = ?
 <sql:param value="${sex}"></sql:param>
```

Comment: Go on what's stopping? Forgot to ask?

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: @almasshaikh i dont know the correct syntax

Comment: it looks ok to me. Which syntax you think is not correct? Did you tried running and got any exception? Basically SO dont do code reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enhanced if condition it will be more easy

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do the zero/one bit, if you aren't using the ${sex} variable anywhere else other than your sql:query.   Your problem can collapse from:

```
<c:set var="sex" value="${param.sex}"/>

<c:if test="$(param.sex=='male')" >
    //set the sex to zero
</c:if>
<c:if test="$(param.sex=='female')" >
   //set the sex to one
</c:if>
...
<sql:query dataSource="${dbcon}" var="result">
    select firstname,lastname from members where sex = ?
    <sql:param value="${sex}">
</sql:param>
```

Down to just this:

```
<sql:query dataSource="${dbcon}" var="result">
    select firstname,lastname from members where sex = ?
    <sql:param value="${param.sex == 'male' ? 0 : 1}">
</sql:param>
```

The point being that you can use param.sex directly in the sql:query statement, and you can use the "ternary operator" instead of using an if statement in this situation.

Google for more on the "JSTL ternary operator" or take a look here (scroll down to Ternary Operations):  http://davidensinger.com/2014/07/fun-with-jstl-in-jsps/

---

UPDATE

To see the ternary operator in action and make sure the param.sex value is the value you expect you can just type this:

```
${param.sex == 'male' ? 0 : 1}
```

On a blank line and it should print either a 0 or 1 to your screen.

Comment: Sure, are you receiving an error?  I will update the answer to show you how the ternary operator works.

Answer (score 0):

select firstname,lastname from members where sex =<%= Enter variable name assumed for sex in this EL %>